# Selecting index with viewlist in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

How do I select an selected index in a listview in visual studio?

Comment: no trying to remove the selected item from a list having major issues...

Comment: accidently deleted your comment O.o sorry!!!!!!!!

Comment: well I ended up using  ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection `selectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;
            int count = selectedItems.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                studentList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
          

            refreshList(); `

Comment: I think that's the correct way of doing it. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ListView.SelectedItems property if you are not using checkboxes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx

You can use ListView.Checkedindices propery if you are using checkboxes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkedindices(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: try listView.SelectedItems[0].Remove